# Shell script to scp rpm to remote server and install it. Needs a variable to pass remote host name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scp

I am attempting to write a sort of menu script which will achieve the below once executed:

1. Ask what user/password you are executing the script as.
2. Ask the remote server i.p. you want to scp files to.
3. Ask the directory where the files are stored locally.
4. Ask the directory where all the files are to be transferred to.
5. Copy all the files.

The first hurdle I have is getting the password stored as a variable within the menu. I think sshpass will be good for that. I would like to configure a menu like this:

```
title="Select example"
prompt="Pick an option:"
options=("A" "B" "C")

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 

    case "$REPLY" in

    1 ) echo "You picked $opt which is option $REPLY";;
    2 ) echo "You picked $opt which is option $REPLY";;
    3 ) echo "You picked $opt which is option $REPLY";;

    $(( ${#options[@]}+1 )) ) echo "Goodbye!"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;

    esac

done
```

But the menu would ask you for username, local directory of files, i.p. of remote server, remote server directory and then run the scp command it constructed.

Something like this:

```
password="your password"
username="username"
Ip="<IP>"
sshpass -p "$password" scp /<PATH>/final.txt $username@$Ip:/root/<PATH>
```

But I'm a bit confused as to how I can put that all of that together so that the menu gathers the required information and then executes the collected input so that it simply constructs an scp command to fire.

Can anyone offer any experience with this to aid me in the construction of the menu script?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you doing it with a menu? Just ask for each input that you need, and put them all into the `scp` command.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean sorry... I want any user to be able to construct a command using the answers to the responses from the menu at any point in time and figured this was the best way to achieve that, but when you say "ask" for the input, can you explain please?

Comment: If the user selects option A, you ask them for the username and password. If they select option B, you ask them for the server IP. And so on, right?

Comment: You ask for the username with `read -p "Username:" username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still need a menu here it is. I modified your script a bit to make it construct/print scp command while entering values one by one.

```
#!/bin/bash

title="Select example"
prompt="Pick an option:"
declare -A options # turn options to an associative array
options[1]='change user name'
options[2]='change user password'
options[3]='change remote host address'
options[4]='change path to source files'
options[5]='change destination path on remote server'

PS3="$prompt "
menu () { # wrap all this to a function to restart it after edition of an element
    echo "$title"
    select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do
        case "$REPLY" in
            1 ) read -p  "${options[1]}: " user;;
            2 ) read -sp "${options[2]}: " pass;; # read password with option -s to disable output
            3 ) read -p  "${options[3]}: " addr;;
            4 ) read -p  "${options[4]}: " from;;
            5 ) read -p  "${options[5]}: " dest;;

            $(( ${#options[@]}+1 )) ) echo "Goodbye!" ; exit;;
            *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";;
        esac
        clear # clear screen to remove inputs
        printf "Creating scp command:\n"
        # we don't want to show password, print *** if password set and 'password not set' if not
        [[ $pass ]] && pass2='***' || pass2='[password not set]'
        # text in [] will be printed if var is empty or not set, it's usefull to add default values to vars ${var:-default_value}
        printf "sshpass -p $pass2 scp -r ${from:-[source not set]}/* ${user:-[user not set]}@${addr:-[host not set]}:${dest:-[destination not set]}/\n\n"
        menu
    done
}

clear # clear screen
menu  # and start menu function
```

And [here](https://github.com/vaniacer/sshto) I've got a script with similar (but richer) functionality, please take a look.

Comment: Wow!! Thanks a lot. This is awesome :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a menu, just ask for each input sequentially.

```
read -p "Username:" username
read -s -p "Password:" password
read -p "Server IP:" ip
read -p "Local directory:" local
read -p "Remote directory" remote
sshpass -p "$password" scp "/$local/final.txt" "$username@$ip:/root/$remote/"
```